# Await for items from Zustand (redux) store to be loaded before rendering page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, redux

I have a react native component that loads information from a zustand store (similar to redux store)

`const members = useMemberList((store) => store.members);`

I want to access specific data from this array of objects but upon using :

`const currentMemberAvatar = retrieveMember[0].avatarFileName;`

it is returning undefined.

I suspect the members are not being loaded prior to accessing them. How can I load the data from the store async before I access the data in it.

const members returns array:

```
[
  {
    "avatarFileName": "brown-dino_128.png",
    "email": null,
    "firstName": "Matt",
    "id": 1,
    "isResponsibleAdult": true,
    "lastName": "Laszcz",
  },
  {
    "avatarFileName": "brown-dino_128.png",
    "email": null,
    "firstName": "Jungmin",
    "id": 2,
    "isResponsibleAdult": false,
    "lastName": "",
  },
  {
    "avatarFileName": "blue-dino_128.png",
    "email": null,
    "firstName": "Timmy",
    "id": 3,
    "isResponsibleAdult": false,
    "lastName": null,
  },
]
```

Here is my functional component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import * as Shadows from "styles/shadows";
import { uploadPathPrefix, uploadRootURL } from "utils/variables";

import { IFamilyMember } from "utils/types";
import useMemberList from "stores/memberList";

interface IPropTypes extends IFamilyMember {}

export default function SettingsMenu({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  avatarFileName,
}: IPropTypes) {

  const [avatarImageName, setAvatarImageName] = useState("");
 
  const members = useMemberList((store) => store.members);

  const currentMemberAvatar = retrieveMember[0].avatarFileName; 
 
  //Returning "undefined" but should return "brown-dino_128.png"
  console.log("Avatar Name I wish to access", currentMemberAvatar);


  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.container, styles.shadow]}>
      <View style={styles.components}>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <Text>Menu</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          right: 0,
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.profileimage}>
          {/* WIP  */}
          <Image
            style={{
              height: "90%",
              aspectRatio: 1,
            }}
            source={{
              uri: `${uploadRootURL}${uploadPathPrefix}/avatars/${avatarImageName}`,
            }}
          ></Image>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Store Creation code:

```
import create from "zustand";

import axiosClient from "utils/axiosClient";
import useGlobal from "./global";
import { IFamilyMember } from "utils/types";
interface IStore {
  members?: IFamilyMember[];
  isFetching: boolean;

  fetchMembers: () => void;
}

const useMemberList = create<IStore>((set, get) => ({
  members: [],
  isFetching: false,

  fetchMembers: async () => {
    if (!!get().isFetching) {
      return;
    }
    set((state) => ({
      ...state,
      isFetching: true,
    }));

    const appToken = useGlobal.getState().appToken;

    try {
      const response = await axiosClient.get("/family/our/member", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${appToken}`,
        },
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        set((state) => ({
          ...state,
          members: response.data.map((x) => ({
            id: x.id,
            firstName: x.first_name,
            lastName: x.last_name,
            email: x.email,
            avatarFileName: x.avatar_file_name,
            isResponsibleAdult: x.is_responsible_adult,
          })),
          isFetching: false,
        }));
      }
    } catch {
      console.log("Error in fetchMembers");
      set((state) => ({
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
      }));
    }
  },
}));

export default useMemberList;
```

Comment: how do you populate the data? please share the store creation code as well. Also, what should your UI show while data is being fetched?

Comment: I have added the code for the store where this members data is created. I hope that helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you set your members.
Normally you need to call the setter function first, otherwise your members array will be empty [].
Your setter function is fetchMembers.
You have to call it to get the data.

And i guess you noticed, that you used retrieveMember, which is never created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).